# I have a local package in my c# project that is stored on different locations depending what dev machine im on

Tags: c#, git, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

Sorry for the super messy title, I had no clue how to describe the issue in one sentence.

So my current situation.
A c# project in Visual studio.
This project references a package that I created locally and is not on NuGet or any other repo.
Recently changed to having two development machines due to COVID, one at home, one at work.
Using git to keep both sides up to date.

Both machines have this package but they are stored on different drives.
And as the location of the package is stored in .csproj file whenever I pull a commit that was made on the other machine it will overwrite the location of the package and say it's unable to find it. Which requires me to remove the reference and readd it. Now, this is a hassle to do each time, but I can't exactly exclude .csproj from git.

As I have no clue how to even google for something like this I came here to ask:
Is there a smarter way to do this?

**Edit**
Its not my style to post a question and then twiddle my thumbs.
Ive come accross NuGet.server to selfhost my package. Dont want to upload it to NuGet itself as its a very case specific package. Is it a good idea to host my private NuGet.server on the webserver I have anyway?

Comment: It seems, that you are violating the entire idea of package management, there is no need to store them locally

Comment: Then how should i do it if my way "Violates the entire idea". While visual studio allows you to add local dll's as references.

Comment: Is MyGet an option? I assume the issue with NuGet is that whatever you built isn't meant for public consumption. As far as self-hosting? Well, the source is there for a reason. If you can and are okay with the process involved, go ahead. If you or your company uses a CI server, a fair number of them can be package servers as well (TeamCity, for instance, has this feature).

Comment: @TiesonT. You're right. The package is a fork of another package but has a case specific modification that is way too specific to be useful to anyone else. Ive started creating a NuGet.server so i can store the package on our own server.

Comment: There's also https://docs.github.com/en/packages/using-github-packages-with-your-projects-ecosystem/configuring-dotnet-cli-for-use-with-github-packages

Comment: I did something like that with a simple Network Share that would be integrated as Nuget Source. We even put copies of _all_ our nuget dependencies there, to avoid the used package version becoming unavailable etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it a good idea to host my private NuGet.server on the webserver I have anyway?

Yes. Either use a server you host in your company, or use a fileshare. You'll need VPN access to your workplace for this to work, or you'll have to make the package server available publicly and password-protect it.

Comment: Going to attempt to put it on our Windows Server that we use to host our private github (Bonobo) as well. Already having fun with a null reference on <% if (Request.IsLocal || ServiceResolver.Current.Resolve<NuGet.Server.Core.Infrastructure.ISettingsProvider>().GetBoolSetting("allowRemoteCacheManagement", false)) { %>. but thats for another day :)

Answer (score -1):

maybe use an environment variable to indicate the path to this package instead of putting it in `.csproj`